# Query without chaining not working - Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, chaining, laravel-query-builder

When I'm trying to fire query without chaining, my browser gets hanged - **no response/error at all**, but query with chaining works fine. I have read at many places that Laravel allows query even without using chaining. But don't know why its not working for me.

And by the way its just a demo project, so there is only 1 table in database named "users" having 50 records in that, so its not like that that browser gets hanged due to high amount of data returned as a query result.

**Not working:**

```
$users = User::where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%Leonie%');

$users -> get();
```

**Working:**

```
$users = User::where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%Leonie%') -> get();
```

I'm using latest Laravel version 5.2. All things are configured properly like database, application configuration etc..

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you don't call `get()` or `first()` (amongst a few others) for example which get a result set, you end up just with a `Builder` object. This is the object which is used to construct queries. In your first example, you assign a `Builder` object to `$users`, but in your second, you assign a `Collection` object.

```
// This assigns the result to $users
$users = User::where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%Leonie%') -> get();

// Doesn't assign the result to $users 
$users = User::where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%Leonie%');

$users -> get();
```

You would need to do

```
$users = User::where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%Leonie%');

$users = $users->get(); // Note the $users =
```

It may be better to name the variable that which is used to store the query builder object something more obvious; such as `$query` perhaps.

```
$query = Users::where();
$users = $query->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using it like this and it works fine. Try it like this and see if it helps.

```
$query = DB::table('your_table_name');
$query->where('name', 'LIKE', 'something');
$some_variable = $query->where('published', 1)->get();
```